# How make a hline value dynamic? i.e not user defined

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to code a dynamic hline in tradingview pinescript so that the hline value changes depending on price, volume, rsi etc etc.
below is an example of a hline thats not dynamic:

```
userinput = input.int(10, "value)
hline(userinput, title = "title", color = color.new(#ffffff, 0), linestyle = hline.style_dotted, linewidth = 1)
```

What I'd like is for the hline to be dynamic instead of being user defined, for example:

```
dynamicvalue = math.avg(variable, anothervariable)
hline(dynamicvalue, title = "dynamic title", color = color.new(#ffffff, 0), linestyle = hline.style_dotted, linewidth = 1)
```

Comment: I too tried feeding a dynamic value / series float values into the HLINE function but it never worked. Seems like the only way is to go for the Plot function.

Answer (score 2):

`hline()` cannot be dynamic.

You can either use [lines](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html) or the following trick with the `plot()` function.

The following indicator will draw horizontal lines from pivot high and low levels. The trick is, using `style=plot.style_circles` in `plot()`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
n = input(5)

var float ph = na
var float pl = na

_ph = ta.pivothigh(n, n)
_pl = ta.pivotlow(n, n)

ph := _ph ? _ph : ph
pl := _pl ? _pl : pl

plot(ph, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green, offset=-n)
plot(pl, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.red, offset=-n)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i'll look at the alternatives to using a hline